# How to build a .sln file using mdtool on OS X

Tags: macos, xamarin, monodevelop, steambot, mdtool

I'm trying to compile a .sln file within /SteamBot-master/SteamBot.sln.
After research I found out that I can only use mdtool within the mdtool directory within Xamarin Studio. So what I enter into the Terminal is the following:

```
"/Applications/Xamarin\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool" -v build SteamBot-master/SteamBot.sln
```

This is the error message I get:

```
-bash: /Applications/Xamarin\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool: No such file or directory
```

The mdtool.exec application is within the MacOS file, I already checked that. When I try to run the application within Xamarin Studio, I get the following error:

```
/Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/.nuget/NuGet.targets: Error: Command 'bash "/Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/.nuget/../.ci/exec-with-retry.sh" mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 /Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/.nuget/NuGet.exe install "packages.config" -source ""  -RequireConsent -solutionDir "/Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/"' exited with code: 127. (SteamTrade)
```

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me fix this so I can use the application. Thank you very much in advance, and I apologize for my lack of programming knowledge.

Edit: New Error Message

```
jo-macbook:~ Johannes$ /Applications/Xamarin\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool -v build SteamBot-master/SteamBot.sln
Xamarin Studio Build Tool
Projektmappe /Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/SteamBot.sln wird geladen
   Projektmappe /Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/SteamBot.sln wird geladen
      Loading projects ..
Erzeuge Projektmappe: SteamBot (Debug)
   SteamTrade (Debug) wird erzeugt

      Build started 30.08.2015 14:59:16.
      __________________________________________________
      Project "/Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/SteamTrade/SteamTrade.csproj"
      (Build target(s)):

        Target RestorePackages:
            Executing: bash
      "/Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/.nuget/../.ci/exec-with-retry.sh" mono
      --runtime=v4.0.30319 /Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/.nuget/NuGet.exe
      install "packages.config" -source ""  -RequireConsent -solutionDir
      "/Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/"
            bash: /Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/.nuget/../.ci/exec-with-retry.sh:
      No such file or directory
      /Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/.nuget/NuGet.targets: error : Command
      'bash "/Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/.nuget/../.ci/exec-with-retry.sh"
      mono --runtime=v4.0.30319
      /Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/.nuget/NuGet.exe install
      "packages.config" -source ""  -RequireConsent -solutionDir
      "/Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/"' exited with code: 127.
        Task "Exec" execution -- FAILED
        Done building target "RestorePackages" in project
      "/Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/SteamTrade/SteamTrade.csproj".-- FAILED

      Done building project
      "/Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/SteamTrade/SteamTrade.csproj".-- FAILED

      Build FAILED.
      Errors:

      /Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/SteamTrade/SteamTrade.csproj (Build) ->
      /Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/.nuget/NuGet.targets (RestorePackages
      target) ->

        /Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/.nuget/NuGet.targets: error : Command
      'bash "/Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/.nuget/../.ci/exec-with-retry.sh"
      mono --runtime=v4.0.30319
      /Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/.nuget/NuGet.exe install
      "packages.config" -source ""  -RequireConsent -solutionDir
      "/Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/"' exited with code: 127.

         0 Warning(s)
         1 Error(s)

      Time Elapsed 00:00:00.1292110
/Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/.nuget/NuGet.targets : error: Command 'bash "/Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/.nuget/../.ci/exec-with-retry.sh" mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 /Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/.nuget/NuGet.exe install "packages.config" -source ""  -RequireConsent -solutionDir "/Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/"' exited with code: 127.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the SteamBot source code from GitHub:

https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot

The `.ci/exec-with-retry.sh` file is missing since this is part of the continuous integration build and it is not on GitHub.

Probably the simplest workaround is to edit the .nuget/NuGet.targets file and change the following line:

```
<RestoreCommand Condition=" '$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT' ">bash "$(NuGetToolsPath)\..\.ci\exec-with-retry.sh" $(NuGetCommand) install "$(PackagesConfig)" -source "$(PackageSources)"  $(RequireConsentSwitch) -solutionDir "$(SolutionDirParsed)"</RestoreCommand>
```

To:

```
<RestoreCommand Condition=" '$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT' ">$(NuGetCommand) install "$(PackagesConfig)" -source "$(PackageSources)"  $(RequireConsentSwitch) -solutionDir "$(SolutionDirParsed)"</RestoreCommand>
```

This just removes the reference to the file and to bash.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and time, it works now! I already thought I'd never get it to work, but thanks to you it works now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have effectively double-escaped the space. Either enclose a command with spaces in it inside double quotes, or put a backslash in front of each space, but not both!

Use either of these:

```
/Applications/"Xamarin Studio.app"/Contents/MacOS/mdtool ...
```

or

```
/Applications/Xamarin\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool ...
```

Comment: I tried both of them but keep getting this error: `"/<Path>//SteamBot-master/.nuget/../.ci/exec-with-retry.sh" mono
      --runtime=v4.0.30319 /<path>/NuGet.exe
      install "packages.config" -source ""  -RequireConsent -solutionDir
      "/Users/Johannes/SteamBot-master/"
        bash: /.../SteamBot-master/.nuget/../.ci/exec-with-retry.sh:
      No such file or directory
      /.../SteamBot-master/.nuget/NuGet.targets: error : Command
      'bash "/.../SteamBot-master/.nuget/../.ci/exec-with-retry.sh"
      /.../exited with code: 127. ` The file appears to be missing

Comment: Yikes! Please click `edit` underneath your original question and paste all extra information in there so everyone can see it properly formatted and read it easily.

Comment: Done! Sorry for the inconvenience.